# angularjs pass select option

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Using MVC 4 and angularjs, I'm trying to pass the selected option to my controller.  I can get this to work:

```
    <select ng-model="record.Line">
        <option value="1" id="line">1</option>
        <option value="2" id="line">2</option>
        <option value="3" id="line">3</option>
    </select>
```

But I can't get this to work, nothing gets passed for the value:

```
    <select ng-model="record.Line" value="record.Line" ng-options="l.name for l in lines" />
```

I've tried using several different options for "value" but no luck.  I would prefer the second option if I can figure out why it isn't working.

Comment: Remove `value`. ng-model will hold the value of the selected option for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ngModel` holds the value of the selected option. So remove the value attribute from the select tag. Assuming the model to be as below

```
$scope.lines = [
    {
        name:"1"
    },
    {
        name:"2"
    },
    {
        name:"3"
    }
];
```

You can change the ng-options to below to specify the values as well:

```
<select ng-model="record.Line" ng-options="l.name as l.name for l in lines" />
```

Comment: That's perfect!  Little embarrassing it was that easy to fix.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can write it like this:

```
<select ng-model="searchDropdown"  ng-class="{active: isDropdownActive}">
            <option ng-repeat="item in data.results" value="{{ item[settings.filterOptions[0].value] }}" >{{ item[settings.filterOptions[0].value] }}</option>
</select>
```